# Publishing appsettings.json to different environment

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-cli

I have three files `appsettings.json` which is a file that I want to store "general shared settings", then I have `appsettings.Development.json` and `appsettings.Production.json`.

When I do a publish from Visual Studio, it seems like only `appsettings.json` is copied and not adding / merge or even just send a simple copy the deployment folder, to me this task should be incorporated into the deployment pipeline.

The question is: how can I do it? What am I missing? Is it not supposed that these actions should be already be incorporated in the process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure your `project.json` has those files included in the list of files to publish and/or copy to output:

```
"buildOptions": {
  "copyToOutput": [
    ...
    "appsettings.json",
    "appsettings.*.json",
    ...
  ],
}
```

or

```
"publishOptions": {
  "include": [
    ...
    "appsettings.json",
    "appsettings.*.json",
    ...
  ]
}
```

The files will not be merged in a single file. They will be logically merged at runtime by the configuration system.