# Publishing environment specific appsettings.ENV.json only to respective environment

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I have multiple environments in my projects- One development, 3 testing environments, 1 integration environment and final production environment.

Hence, we decided to go for environment specific appsettings.ENVNAME.json

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38710269/publishing-appsettings-json-to-different-environment) we were following `project.json`-

```
"publishOptions": {
  "include": [
    ...
    "appsettings.json",
    "appsettings.*.json",
    ...
  ]
}
```

By doing, we were publishing appsetting.PROD.json to even in different TEST environments, which is wrong.

I understand that, we can control loading of appsettings files in startup like this-

```
.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);
```

But in this case too, other files are available. (Someone by mistake change env name and it will start picking up details of other environment)

Now (as per our Audit team), we need to publish environment specific **appsettings.ENVNAME.json** only to corresponding environment.

How to achieve this using project.json? Do we need write separate script for this? What is the best way to tackle this scenario?

Comment: _Someone by mistake change env name and it will start picking up details of other environment_ is as good as an argument as _Someone by mistake publishes wrong appsettings.envname.json file and it will start picking up details of other environment_, both are prone to the same type of manual errors. You can make your enviornment file mandatory rather than optional in your example. If someone changes it to non-existing environment name, it runs into an error. The thing is, not your package should decide which is the environment mode, but your server you deploy it on

Comment: Even if I make it mandatory, still other environment files will be part of my publish folder. Audit team will not approve this. Here, our intention is to automate publishing process based on environment name.

Comment: You talk about such stringent audit processes and, yet, dev's can publish to staging and production directly? Why not publish this to a separate location and then copy the required files to the needed location ?

Answer (score 0):

For security reason (intended or by mistake) I do (personally) avoid to include Staging/Production configuration files in the repository or on a computer used for development. These files might contain sensitive information and, as you said, big mistakes can occur if the wrong configuration file is used or modified.

Moreover a configuration file for production would not change too much so you can easily modify it manually when needed. To conclude I only use one `appsettings.json` per environnement. It is safer and actually easier in my opinion.